# Suppress LightGBM warnings in Optuna

Tags: lightgbm, optuna

I am getting below warnings while I am using Optuna to tune my model.
Please tell me how to suppress these warnings?

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] feature_fraction is set=0.2, colsample_bytree=1.0 will be ignored. Current value: feature_fraction=0.2
[LightGBM] [Warning] min_data_in_leaf is set=5400, min_child_samples=20 will be ignored. Current value: min_data_in_leaf=5400
[LightGBM] [Warning] min_gain_to_split is set=13.203719815769512, min_split_gain=0.0 will be ignored. Current value: min_gain_to_split=13.203719815769512
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would you like to ignore it? 
Variables such as `colsample_bytree` (from the first warning) are default variables that are defined in the LGBM class. `feature_fraction` is just it's alias. So if you'd rename the variable to `colsample_bytree`, there would be no warning. And it won't change the outcome of the coding. Same goes for other warnings such as this one.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Optuna but I ran into this issue using Python/lightgbm.

As of v3.3.2, [the parameters tuning page](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html) included parameters that seem to be renamed, deprecated, or duplicative. If, however, you stick to setting/tuning the parameters specified in the model object you can avoid this warning.

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
params = LGBMRegressor().get_params()
print(params)
```

These are the only parameters you want to set. If you want to be able to include all the parameters, you could do something like below.

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
lgr = LGBMRegressor()
params = lgr.get_params()
aliases = [
    {'min_child_weight', 'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf'},
    {'min_child_samples', 'min_data_in_leaf'},
    {'colsample_bytree', 'feature_fraction'},
    {'subsample', 'bagging_fraction'}
]
for alias in aliases:
    if len(alias & set(params)) == 2:
        arg = random.choice(sorted(alias))
        params[arg] = None
lgr = LGBMRegressor(**params)
```

The code sets one or the other in each parameter pair that seems to be duplicative. Now, when you call `lgr.fit(X, y)` you should not get the warning.